# advanced.session-leak after sometime of starting spark thrift server with datastax cassandra connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector, spark-thriftserver

Hi I am getting the following error after some time of inactivity.

```
Error: Error running query: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: withValue(advanced.reconnection-policy.base-delay): No configuration setting found for key 'advanced.session-leak' (state=,code=0)
```

restarting thrift server seems to solve the issue for sometime.

Comment: what version of Spark Cassandra Connector there?

Comment: 3.0 is the version @AlexOtt